# Ubuntu indicators in Mate or XFCE

Tags: 13.10, indicator

Is there any chance to put Ubuntu indicators in XFCE or Mate. I want classic desktop environment like we had in Ubuntu before Unity came, but whichever DE I use it have ugly indicators

Comment: Mate doesn't support gtk3 indicators yet. If you want Ubuntu indicators use Gnome-Flashback session.All indicator will work except indicator-applet-appmenu which is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-panel/+bug/1250657). In trusty it uses gnome-panel-3.8 which also has few bugs, but will be fixed in next release.

Answer (score 0):

I know my [indicators](https://launchpad.net/~thebernmeister/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) work under Xubuntu (XFCE) - untested on Mate.

I'd suggest you peruse [What Application Indicators are available?](https://askubuntu.com/q/30334/67335), choose your indicator(s) and then trial and error.